# Can I stack more spawn rate enhancement(s)?

Tags: terraria

[Blood Moon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blood_moon), [Battle Potion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Battle_Potion), and a [water candle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_candle) placed. Is there any other way or do any of these work by adding more? (more players using battle potion, or more water candles on the screen)

Comment: The effects stack, but the candle must be **held** not placed.

Comment: Water Candle only works when it's equipped. Meaning that when you place it somewhere, it won't work.

Comment: If watercandle worked from the time its placed on then it would be immediately active, since there are multiple ones places in the dungeon.

Comment: @Batophobia the "official" wiki claims placed water candles do increase enemy spawns if they are nearby, and also stack with held water candles as of 1.2, though I don't know what their source is. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Candle

Answer (score 3):

[The Jungle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle) has an increased spawn rate. There's a chart [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC_spawning) showing the spawn rates, and it shows that the Jungle during a Blood Moon has a 1-in-60 chance of a monster spawning every 'tick', compared to 1 in 108 during Blood Moon in other biomes.

The Jungle also has the highest spawn limit, with a limit of 15 mobs during a Blood Moon, vs. 11 in other biomes.

Comment: So THAT's why I seem to be constantly swarmed by jungle bats and hornets there.